# SQL employee Query to get annual salary Oracle HRMS

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to get an employee's annual salary using their FTE in a SQL query?

This is the query to get the salary. How do I incorporate the FTE component?

```
SELECT papf.employee_number,papf.full_name,pj.NAME job,
       pap.NAME as Designation ,pg.NAME as Grade , haou.NAME 
       ORGANIZATION,ppp.creation_date createDate,
       ppp.PROPOSED_SALARY as salary
FROM per_all_people_f papf
,per_all_assignments_f paaf
,per_jobs pj
,per_grades pg
,hr_all_organization_units haou
,per_position_definitions ppd
,per_all_positions pap
,per_pay_proposals ppp
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
AND papf.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
AND papf.employee_number IS NOT NULL
AND paaf.person_id = papf.person_id
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date AND paaf.effective_end_date
AND paaf.job_id = pj.job_id
AND paaf.organization_id = haou.organization_id
AND paaf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
AND paaf.position_id = pap.position_id
AND pap.position_definition_id = ppd.position_definition_id
AND ppp.pay_proposal_id in (SELECT MAX (pay_proposal_id)
FROM per_pay_proposals
WHERE assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id)
order by to_number(papf.employee_number)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and you current attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: @GMB Added the code I have written. I need to know how to use FTE to derive the annual salary?

Comment: So, you have 8 tables joined together, and you would like us to guess which of those tables has information about the FTE component?

Comment: @mark stewart if you have worked on Oracle EBS HRMS module then you would have an idea of how to go about it. The query i have shared is to calculate the salary. I was hoping someone would be able to help out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT papf.employee_number,
   papf.full_name,
   pj.NAME job,
   pap.NAME as Designation,
   pg.NAME as Grade,
   haou.NAME ORGANIZATION,
   ppp.creation_date createDate,
   (ppp.PROPOSED_SALARY * paaf.fte) as adjusted_salary  -- Adjust salary 
   --based on FTE
 FROM per_all_people_f papf
JOIN per_all_assignments_f paaf ON paaf.person_id = papf.person_id
JOIN per_jobs pj ON paaf.job_id = pj.job_id
JOIN per_grades pg ON paaf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
JOIN hr_all_organization_units haou ON paaf.organization_id = 
haou.organization_id
JOIN per_position_definitions ppd ON paaf.position_id = pap.position_id
JOIN per_all_positions pap ON pap.position_definition_id = 
ppd.position_definition_id
JOIN per_pay_proposals ppp ON ppp.pay_proposal_id = (
SELECT MAX(pay_proposal_id)
FROM per_pay_proposals
WHERE assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id
)
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
AND papf.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
AND papf.employee_number IS NOT NULL
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date AND paaf.effective_end_date
ORDER BY to_number(papf.employee_number);
```